# How to match a data that appears 0 or 1 times in grok?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I appreciate if someone can help me out with the logstash frok.

I am trying to create a single grok definition for below samples. My goal is to parse the *subject* as a field.

1. t1='t1', t2='t2', subject='subj', t3='hoge'
2. t1='t1', subject='subj', t3='hoge'
3. t1='t1', t3='hoge'

Below works fine if *subject* always exists.

```
t1=%{QS}, (%{NOTSPACE:key}=%{NOTSPACE:value}, )*subject=%{QS:subject}
```

However, I will need to deal with sample No.3 , so if I change the grok definition as below, then sample No1. and No2. is not working now.

```
t1=%{QS}, (%{NOTSPACE:key}=%{NOTSPACE:value}, )*(subject=%{QS:subject})?
```

Is there any good grok definition that can work with all samples?

Comment: you're pattern of `(%{NOTSPACE:key}=%{NOTSPACE:value}, )*` specifically matches the `subject='x'` portion.  Have you tried the `kv` filter?

Comment: @Alcanzar Thanks for the reply. Yes I tried `kv` . But I am reluctant to use this because the *subject* sometimes include unexpected characters like , `=[]<>`, which might affect to `kv` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your best bet is probably to just conditionally parse the subject out:

```
if [message] =~ /subject/ {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "subject=%{QS:subject}" }
  }
}
```

you can still do your unconditional `grok` as well and all matches will be added to the event.

Comment: I see. I also think this is the most stable way. Thanks for your time!